# Click away from image to shrink it back down after expanded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a gallery of pics that expand to full size when you click them and shrink back to normal when you click them a second time... my issue is that if I click multiple pictures, they will all enlarge and stack without the first ones returning to their original size. I'm wondering if there is an easy way to either force all of the other pics back to the smaller size when one is clicked for enlargement, or if there is a way to make it so you have to click somewhere away from the enlarged pic to get it to return to the smaller size.

Here's my code, fiddle link at the bottom
(click the second pic and then the first to see what I'm talking about)

```
        <div id="Gpic1">
        <img class='galleryPics' id='pic1' src='http://i.imgur.com/urxD24P.jpg?1'>
    </div>
    <div id="Gpic2">
        <img class='galleryPics' id='pic2' src='http://i.imgur.com/JbJXjsf.jpg?1'>
    </div>


    #Gpic1 {
        float: left;
        width: 187px;
        height: 280px;
        margin-left: 5%;
        display: inline-block;
        background: black;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #pic1 {
        width: 187px;
        height: 280px;
    }
    #Gpic2 {
        float: left;
        width: 187px;
        height: 280px;
        margin-left: 5%;
        display: inline-block;
        background: black;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #pic2 {
        width: 187px;
        height: 280px;
    }
    .enlarged {
        border: 10px solid #e5dbcc;
        position: absolute;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 7px 7px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
        -moz-box-shadow: 7px 7px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
        box-shadow: 7px 7px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    }


 $('#Gpic1').hover(function () {
     if (!$(this).find('img').hasClass('enlarged')) {
         $(this).find('img').fadeTo(500, 0.5);
     }
 }, function () {
     $(this).find('img').fadeTo(500, 1);
 });

 $('#pic1').click(function () {
     $(this).fadeTo(0, 1);
     if ($(this).hasClass('enlarged')) {
         $(this).removeClass('enlarged');

         $(this).stop().animate({
             width: 187,
             height: 280
         }, 0,

         function () {
             $(this).parent().removeClass('ontop');
             $('#Gpic1').css('background', 'black');
         });
     } else {
         $(this).addClass('enlarged')
         $(this).parent().addClass('ontop');
         $(this).stop().animate({
             width: 533,
             height: 800,
             left: +100,
             bottom: +50
         }, 200);
         $('#Gpic1').css('background', 'none');

     }

 });

 $('#Gpic2').hover(function () {
     if (!$(this).find('img').hasClass('enlarged')) {
         $(this).find('img').fadeTo(500, 0.5);
     }
 }, function () {
     $(this).find('img').fadeTo(500, 1);
 });

 $('#pic2').click(function () {
     $(this).fadeTo(0, 1);
     if ($(this).hasClass('enlarged')) {
         $(this).removeClass('enlarged');

         $(this).stop().animate({
             width: 187,
             height: 280
         }, 0,

         function () {
             $(this).parent().removeClass('ontop');
             $('#Gpic2').css('background', 'black');
         });
     } else {
         $(this).addClass('enlarged')
         $(this).parent().addClass('ontop');
         $(this).stop().animate({
             width: 533,
             height: 800,
             left: +100,
             bottom: +50
         }, 200);
         $('#Gpic2').css('background', 'none');

     }

 });
```

EDIT ---- fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Td6tT/4/

Comment: Ah! so sorry! here: http://jsfiddle.net/Td6tT/4/

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a jQuery function to select all picture elements of the given class "enlarged" and shrink them before enlarging the next one:

```
$("img.enlarged").removeClass("enlarged");
```

So in your code, for example:

```
$('#pic1').click(function () {
 $(this).fadeTo(0, 1);
 if ($(this).hasClass('enlarged')) {
     $(this).removeClass('enlarged');

     $(this).stop().animate({
         width: 187,
         height: 280
     }, 0,

     function () {
         $(this).parent().removeClass('ontop');
         $('#Gpic1').css('background', 'black');
     });
 } else {

     //Add the following line
     $("img.enlarged").removeClass("enlarged");

     $(this).addClass('enlarged')
     $(this).parent().addClass('ontop');
     $(this).stop().animate({
         width: 533,
         height: 800,
         left: +100,
         bottom: +50
     }, 200);
         $('#Gpic1').css('background', 'none');

     }

 });
```

Voila!

Comment: I tried adding that and it almost worked, except that the picture does not take back it's original size :/  http://jsfiddle.net/Td6tT/5/

Answer (score 0):

There are really a couple ways to do this, and it depends on how you feel about different approaches. Perhaps the easiest thing to do, since you're already basing it on classes would be to add something like `$('.enlarged').removeClass('enlarged')` to the start of the clickhandler section that deals with enlarging a new image. That way, when you click to enlarge another image, all other images that are enlarged will shrink.

If you prefer, you could create a variable to store whichever one is currently open and shrink it in the same way, as well, though I think the above suggestion is nicer as it keeps everything within the function scope.

For a general 'clickaway' function, you may also consider using [.blur](http://api.jquery.com/blur/), but you'd need to give the image focus when it is clicked using [.focus](http://api.jquery.com/focus/).